# Deactivate the Current Ansible User with Ansible

Tags: ansible

In setting up a new Raspberry Pi with Ansible, I would like to perform the following actions:

- Using the default `pi` user, create a new user named `my_new_admin`
- Using the new `my_new_admin` user, deactivate the default `pi` user
- Continue executing the playbook as `my_new_admin`

I am finding this difficult to achieve in a single playbook. Is it even possible to switch the active user like this in Ansible?

```yaml
# inventory.yaml
---
all:
  children:
    rpis:
      hosts:
        myraspberrypi.example.com:
          ansible_user: my_new_admin  # or should `pi` go here?
...
```

```yaml
# initialize.yaml
- hosts: rpis
  remote_user: 'pi'
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: 'create new user'
      user:
        name: 'my_new_admin'
        append: true
        groups:
          - 'sudo'
    - name: 'add SSH key to my_new_admin'
      *snip*
    - name: 'lock default user'
      remote_user: 'my_new_admin'
      user:
        name: 'pi'
        expires: '{{ ("1970-01-02 00:00:00" | to_datetime).timestamp() | float }}'
        password_lock: true
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch users, the easiest solution is to start another play.  For example, the following playbook will run the first play as user `pi` and the second play as user `root`:

```
- hosts: pi
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: pi
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
      register: whoami

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ whoami.stdout }}"

- hosts: pi
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
      register: whoami

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ whoami.stdout }}"
```

In this playbook I'm being explicit about `remote_user` in both plays, but you could also set a user in your inventory and only override it when necessary.  E.g., if I have:

```
pi ansible_host=raspberrypi.local ansible_user=root
```

Then I could rewrite the above playbook like this:

```
- hosts: pi
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_user: pi
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
      register: whoami

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ whoami.stdout }}"

- hosts: pi
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
      register: whoami

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ whoami.stdout }}"
```

Note that I'm setting the `ansible_user` variable here rather than using `remote_user`, because it looks as if `ansible_user` has precedence.

Comment: Of course! I didn't realize that you can have multiple plays per playbook. Now that you say it, it's very clear. Thank you!